# How to replace list of elements in a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to parse some HTML content created in WYSIWYG editor, I have the HTML string in a  variable `content` , I need however to get all `img` tags in this HTML string , change their src with some logic ( a function) and replace the old img tag with the new ones.

Here is the code responsible for the first part of the logic:

```
      let element = document.createElement( 'html' );
      element.innerHTML = content
```

Now `element` is a dummy HTML DOM that contains the parsed HTML string I had in `content` .
Now I'm getting the list of images  and looping through them, changing the `src` attribute.

```
      let img_list = element.getElementsByTagName( 'img' ); 
      for (var i = 0; i < img_list.length; i++) {
        some_src = someFunction()
        img_list[i].setAttribute("src",some_src)
      }
```

Now the images in `img_list` are updated with the new source, I need to replace the old img in content with the new images, how can I do that ? (I can't add IDs to the images in `content`).

Comment: There is no magic there, this should already be working, why the image src should not be updated ? Your content is up to date and you can use element.innerHTML to read that out, try `console.log(element.innerHTML)` after your modifications.

Comment: @AminZoubaa Indeed, I don't knwo why it didn't work, seems like I missed something in the original code, thank you for pointing it out !

Comment: i figured it out, you are creating a `html` dom element insted of an div or something similar. That generates a whole new html tree with html -> head/body. that is not ideal. Instead you want to use a `div` element, checkout my answer. That should work out of the box for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can manipulate a html string and get an html string back. May that can help you.

```js
const modContent = (content) => {
  // create a html dom element
  const virtualHtml = document.createElement('div');
  
  // pass the content to the html dom element
  // the html will be interpreted automatically
  virtualHtml.innerHTML = content;

  // find all images
  const images = virtualHtml.querySelectorAll('img');

  /* start modification */

    // loop througth all images
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
      // update image path
      image.src = `new-url/${index + 1}.jpg`;
    });
  
  /* end modification */

  // return innerHTML wich will be converted automatically to a string
  return virtualHtml.innerHTML;
}

let content = `<div>
  <img src="url/1.png" />
  <img src="url/2.png" />
  <img src="url/3.png" />
  <img src="url/4.png" />
  <img src="url/5.png" />
</div>`;

console.log('old content -> ', content);

// modify content
content = modContent(content);
console.log('new content -> ', content);
```